# Visual Studio 2017: which template to use for additional dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution in `Visual Studio 2017` which includes several `C#` projects.

However, the application I'm developing also requires an additional component which is not written in a language supported by Visual Studio (it's a custom javascript library with its own custom compilation/code generation script).

I would like to include this component (it's just a bunch of text files, mainly .js and some others) in my Visual Studio solution, so I have everything in one place. Also, if I include it as a VS project, I can leverage the Pre-Build / Post-Build events to run the component's compilation script, without having to manually run a batch file like I'm doing now.

My question is: which Visual Studio "project type" (i.e.: template) is best for this scenario? I don't need to compile anything, the project only needs to be a "file container" basically...

Comment: C++ > General > Makefile project.  Not only good for C++ or projects built with NMake.  You get the option to name the dependencies and to specify the exact build commands.

Comment: @HansPassant: I just tried, but it doesn't seem to support subfolders... whenever I drag a folder onto it, nothing happens. Only "flat" files get added...